# node.js get file descriptor of socket?

Tags: sockets, node.js, file-descriptor

How can I get the file descriptor (respectively its path) of a socket?

I can open a file descriptor when I know its path like this:

```
var fd = require("fs").createReadStream(pathOfFileDescriptor);
```

for example

```
require("fs").createReadStream("/proc/"+process.pid+"/fd/0").on("data",function(d){
    console.log("The following data comes from stdin: "+d);
});
```

Now, how can I know which file descriptor file is for which socket?

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems not to be possible at the moment.
Maybe it will come in future versions of node.js

Comment: It must be possible :) i will add an answer to this question if you dont beat me to it.